# xdmp-newtimestamp issue after Marklogic upgrade

Tags: marklogic

Recently we have upgraded our MarkLogic from ML 7.0-3 to ML8.0-7 and we are encountering a frequent error while doing feed processing. We
have noticed that when the scheduler has started the batch processing, this error of **XDMP-NEWSTAMP** occurs far too many times. So if we run the feed processing, 8 out of 10 times we are seeing this error.

This issue was never encountered in ML 7 and also if we run the process in a single node, we don't see the error but when we are running this process in the cluster(3 nodes), this issue is occurring. Please suggest what has changed in ML8 that is causing this issue to prompt up so frequently and remediation steps to handle this issue.

Following are the messages from the error logs that can throw some more light.

> 2017-12-09 13:07:07.766 Warning: Forest MetadataManager-DB-3 fast query timestamp (15128246520780909) lags commit timestamp (15128248242145655) by 172136 ms
>
> 2017-12-09 13:07:07.782 Warning: Forest MetadataManager-DB-4 fast query timestamp (15128246520780909)lags commit timestamp (15128248242145655) by 172136 ms
>
> 2017-12-09 13:07:30.813 Warning: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in rebalance of forest MetadataManager-DB-3: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246686294726)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:07:30.813 Warning: XDMP-FORESTERR: Error in rebalance of forest MetadataManager-DB-4: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246686294726)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:08:41.076 Info: XDMP-DEADLOCK: Deadlock detected locking MetadataManager-DB-4 http://www.bsigroup.com/metadata/biblioCore/00-1439579551.xml
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:15.794 Warning: Forest MetadataManager-DB-3 fast query timestamp (15128246520780909) lags commit timestamp (15128249402836420) by 288205 ms
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:15.810 Warning: Forest MetadataManager-DB-4 fast query timestamp (15128246520780909) lags commit timestamp (15128249402836420) by 288205 ms
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.731 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-4, session=15802507183588976425, urikey=16093145954678056618 2017-12-09
>
> 13:09:41.732 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-4, session=2085612361749210104, urikey=18317592754448257267
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.734 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-4, session=6209169002811192942, urikey=3102218889495799330
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.735 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-3, session=6209169002811192942, urikey=648935519615700171
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.735 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-3, session=12490873922076400084, urikey=3095712996168162718
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.739 Debug: Missing lock:  forest=MetadataManager-DB-4, session=12490873922076400084, urikey=14234980101588629362
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.740 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.740 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.740 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.742 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.744 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.746 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.747 Warning: Forest MetadataManager-DB-4 fast query timestamp (15128249781414955) lags commit timestamp (15128249781414955) by 0 ms
>
> 2017-12-09 13:09:41.748 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> import module namespace e...", (fn:QName("","extension-name"), "feedsService", fn:QName("","method"), ...), different-transaction...) -- Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128246526555070)
>
> 2017-12-09 14:43:17.759 Notice: TaskServer: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128300299401460)
>
> 2017-12-09 14:43:18.791 Info: MetadataManager-REST: Status 500: XDMP-NEWSTAMP: Timestamp too new for forest MetadataManager-DB-3 (15128300299401460)

Comment: Please reach out to support if you are entitled. They should be able to explain, and guide you through the proper solution.